# Swift automatically creating temporary dictionaries

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, dictionary

I'm working with a datasource for a UITableView where I need an array with dictionaries.

I tried making an array, and filling it with dictionaries in a for loop like this.

```
temporaryDataDict = [:]
temporaryDataDict = ["name":stockName, "ticker":ticker, "lastPrice":lastPrice, "purchasePrice":purchasePrice, "weight":weight, "daysHeld":daysHeld]
temporaryDataArray.append(temporaryDataDict)
```

But of course, when I start filling my tableView with the dataSource. I end up for 23 of the exact same dictionaries (the last one in the for loop).

This is of course, because it's changing the dictionary every time.

I havn't been able to find a way to keep the data in the dictionaries, or programatically make a new dictionary every time (since they need a new name otherwise it'll overwrite the data).

So how can I programatically make dictionaries everytime a for loop runs, then get the keys & values of these dictionaries?

or am I going about this completely wrong?

If it helps, here's the kind of data I'm working with.

I have a stock (or item) with 6 properties. So I think it makes the most sense to have an array where every item in the array is the "stock" as a dictionary that contains the 6 properties.

So is it possible to make swift automatically create these dictionaries for me? Since I don't know the amount of dictionaries needed.

PS.
I know this is what CoreData is for. I'm using these arrays and Dictionaries to later fill in my CoreData.

If the above isn't possible I am aware that I can probably create a new CoreData entity to accomplish what I want, but it doesn't seem like the best way to go about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just make a Stock class or struct for the data you need instead of storing it in a dictionary?

Comment: Instead of a dictionary of six items create a data object (class) with these six properties, create them and add then to the array.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Most definitely the way to go. Could either of you possibly post an answer with an explanation of how I can access the specific datapoints in either a class or a struct?

Comment: @MarkL Can you post the entirety of the relevant code, such as the loop that you are using and what you need the array of stocks for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that a dictionary is the best sort of data structure to use in this case. Since typically a dictionary is composed of a unique key and a value.

**I have edited this answer.** Originally I suggested creating a class containing a property for each record field. Then I figured that this could be done using a tuple via a `typealias` for each record. Using a `typealias` gets around an issue related to creating arrays of tuples.

**ETA: However please read the comments because Zaph who knows more about this than me reckons that using a Class is a stronger solution.**

This is my tuple based solution. Most of what follows is just about quickly creating some dummy data:

```
    typealias StockRecord = (stockName:String, ticker: String, lastPrice: Double, purchasePrice: Double, weight: Double, daysHeld: Int)

    var temporaryDataArray = [StockRecord]()

    // use a loop to create dummy records and add each to the array
    // rough and ready - just to test the solution
    var loopCounter: Int
    for loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <= 23; loopCounter++ {

        //some dummy field values for each record
        var stockName = "stockName" + ("\(loopCounter)")
        var ticker = "ticker" + ("\(loopCounter)")
        var lastPrice = Double(loopCounter)
        var purchasePrice = Double(loopCounter)
        var weight = Double(loopCounter)
        var daysHeld = loopCounter

        var newRecord = (stockName, ticker, lastPrice, purchasePrice, weight, daysHeld)
        temporaryDataArray.append(newRecord)
    }
```

ETA: Iterate over the array - eg:

```
for recordEntry in temporaryDataArray {
    var a = recordEntry.stockName
    var b = recordEntry.ticker
    // etc
}
```

Or with enumeration - eg:

```
for (count,recordEntry) in enumerate(temporaryDataArray) {
    println("\(count)  \(recordEntry)")
}
```

Output:

```
0  (stockName0, ticker0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0)
1  (stockName1, ticker1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1)
2  (stockName2, ticker2, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2)
3  (stockName3, ticker3, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3)
etc
```

Comment: Why do you believe a `typealias` is a better solution than a `class`? Also opening and closing braces do not match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been trying to implement either a class or this typealias for a bit now. But I can't seem to figure out how to get a specific datapoint. E.g. if I need to get lastPrice of the 4th item in the array, how would I go about that? - Would it help if I proved some more code in form of how I'm looping through things?

Comment: @zaph - I have removed the extra brace - thanks for noting that. The main reason I have used a `typealias` is because it neatly solves issues related to using tuples with arrays. I have used a tuple because it seems like a neater and more Swift like solution. But I do not know for certain that this is the best solution and would be interested to know what other people think is best and why.

Comment: @Mark L: In this example the lastPrice of the 4th item in the array would be `temporaryDataArray[3].lastPrice` eg `println(temporaryDataArray[3].lastPrice)`

Comment: @simons The point is encapsulation, a class is a cohesive unit, in this case  a data model. Typically a data model would have accessors and an initializer and the details of the storage would be hidden from the user of the class instance. That way the actual storage could be changed without any impact on the user.

Comment: @zaph - good points. My understanding of the question is that the intention here  is to create a temporary data structure. A tuple seems like a light-weight solution in this case. Incidentally - IIRC the Stanford Swift course teaches to avoid using inits wherever possible. I wonder whether that is big difference with the Swift approach.

Comment: I was using the tern "init" generically, the answer code has has initialization of the values. While much has been learned about how to write good sustainable code little of that is used, that is why coding is not engineering.

Comment: @zaph - I have further edited my answer to note your wise perspective. For the benefit of anyone coming to this thread at a later date via search.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! @simons I've been trying to implement this. I think I got the tuple working correctly, but I should have been more specific when I asked for an example output. I need to loop through all the values as well, not just get a single value. Unless I just add a counter and do e.g. `temporaryDataArray[i].lastPrice` etc. etc.

Comment: I got it set up with a simple counter, using the above method. It seems to work, an odd bug with 1 specific item showing up several times? But that's unrelated to this question. Thank you so much for the help. (Went with the tuple as an example was provided)

Comment: @Mark L Not sure I understand the question here. You don't really need a counter to get stuff back out of the array. You can iterate over the array using `for recordEntry in temporaryDataArray`. But you can enumerate that using eg - `for (counter, recordEntry) in enumerate(temporaryDataArray)`. I have edited the answer at the bottom of the code to demonstrate this.

Comment: @Simons added your way to iterate through the Array, much better than a loop inside a loop based on a counter. Once again thank you so much!

Comment: I'd like to add one more important thing:  You'll find a Struct is much better suited for this task.  A Struct is inherently immutable, and it's handled on the stack rather than on the heap.  You'll get better performance, and you'll sleep safe knowing that you're not going to accidentally overwrite a memory pointer with a new object.  A struct will also give you a bit of convenience in automatically defining an init function with all of your properties.